# Rails 3 + activerecord, the best way to "mass update" a single field for all the records that meet a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In rails 3, using activerecord, is there a single-query way to set the **:hidden** field to **TRUE** for all records that meet a condition ... say, for example, `:condition => [ "phonenum = ?", some_phone_number ]`

If a single query cannot do it, what IS the optimal approach?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) with the optional second parameter for the condition:

```
Model.update_all({ hidden: true }, { phonenum: some_phone_number})
```

Comment: What about the case where a value is less than a certain value for ex update_all( { :hidden => true  }, {  :date_created < a_certain_date })  is this possible?

Comment: @ctilley79, I think this should work: `Model.where("date_create < ?", a_certain_date).update_all(hidden: true)`

Answer (score 87):

The update_all does not allow conditions in rails 3. You can use combination of scope and update_all

```
Model.where(phonenum: some_phone_number).update_all(hidden: true)
```

Reference: http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

Comment: **This is wrong**. The page says "**supplying any option**", per the paragraph just above the method list describing the various options which can go in the `options` hash. This does not include the `conditions` argument on `update_all()`.

Comment: I agree he's wrong.  according to the API Avatar.update_all ['migrated_at = ?', Time.now.utc], ['migrated_at > ?', 1.week.ago] will set migrated = now where migrated_at is within a week.

Comment: As per rails 4 documentation, the above suggested method is indeed the way to go - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all  - # Update all books with 'Rails' in their title
Book.where('title LIKE ?', '%Rails%').update_all(author: 'David')

Answer (score 5):

If you want to trigger callbacks:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.update_each(updates)
    find_each { |model| model.update(updates) }
  end

  def self.update_each!(updates)
    find_each { |model| model.update!(updates) }
  end
end
```

Then:

```
Model.where(phonenum: some_phone_number).update_each(hidden: true)
```