# mass increment field by 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a query `update deals set count = count + 1`. In Rails, when I do this using ActiveRecord, I can think of

```
Deal.all.each { |deal| deal.update_attribute(:count => (deal.count + 1))}
```

and this take a lot more SQL queries instead of one query. Is there a better way to do this in Rails (not using the SQL query directly in the Rails app).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912510/rails-3-activerecord-the-best-way-to-mass-update-a-single-field-for-all-the

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `ActiveRelation update_all` Updates all records with details given if they match a set of conditions supplied, limits and order can also be supplied. This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight to the database. It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class

Comment: @noodi Yes, I know that and it is shown in the query I have stated `update deals set count = count + 1`.. What I am asking is how you can achieve it in Rails. Can you please show?

Comment: @rubyprince you can do, Deal.update_all("count = count + 1"). But, isn't safe. Passing String arguments to update_all is an invitation to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Syed Aslam How can an SQL injection occur where you are passing a static string?

Answer (score 21):

```
Deal.update_all("count = count + 1")
```

outputs

```
UPDATE "deals" SET count = count + 1
```

And with a conditional:

```
Deal.where(order_id: 2).update_all("count = count + 1")
```

outputs

```
UPDATE "deals" SET count = count + 1 WHERE "deals"."order_id" = 2
```

Comment: In your two outputs I think you meant "count + 1" where you have "count - 1".