# Mass update by ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, batch-updates

In the table about 10,000-20,000 objects. I have about 1000 id entries, which you want to change one value. How to do this correctly? I don't want to use each which will be 1000 times INSERT. I think this is not correct.

P.S. This is a normal variant?

```
accounts_closes = Account.where(:alfa_flag => false).pluck(:id)

Account.transaction do
  accounts_closes.each do |account_id|
    Account.connection.execute 'UPDATE accounts SET open = false WHERE id = ' + account_id + ';'
  end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 + activerecord, the best way to "mass update" a single field for all the records that meet a condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912510/rails-3-activerecord-the-best-way-to-mass-update-a-single-field-for-all-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912510/rails-3-activerecord-the-best-way-to-mass-update-a-single-field-for-all-the), basically you should use [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all), which constructs single update query for all records of one table. If you need to update only certain records, you can just use **where** before the update and chain it, like:

```
Book.where('title LIKE ?', '%Rails%').update_all(author: 'David')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, your offer for any and all records. And I need to change only some.

check p.s. block on question

Comment: That is not quite true, see the links I have posted, I have added an example, so it will be more obvious how to accomplish it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have complicated what could be done easier. Thank you!

Account.where(:alfa_flag => false).update_all(open: false)